# convert multi arrays in to object array with properties

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a txt file that I split by the tabs, then I map out each line to an array. I would like to make these arrays

```
    [
    "saddle (seat)",
    "asiento"
  ],
  [
    "seat clamp",
    "abrazadera de asiento"
  ],
```

Into something like this, using Eng and Spa as properties:

```
{    Eng: saddle (seat),
     Spa: asiento,
     Eng: seat clamp,
     Spa: abrazadera de asiento
}
```

This is my current code

```
var fs = require('fs');

var output = fs.readFileSync('component names.txt', 'utf8')
    .replace(/(\r)/gm, "")
    .split('\n')
    .map(line => line.split('\t'))
     /* .reduce(() => {}, )
   components = []
    components[].push({
    Eng: line[0],
    Spa: line[1]
    }) */

console.log('output:', JSON.stringify(output, null, 2));
```

Comment: You can't have multiple properties of the same name, the latter ones will overwrite the former ones

Comment: Maybe you want and array of objects like: `arr= [{Eng: "saddle (seat)", Spa: "asiento"} ,{Eng: "someEng", Spa:"someSpa"}, ...]`

Comment: zip them together and then map them into an array of objects,

Comment: @MarkMeyer yes, can you show me how?

Comment: @akaphenom can you show me how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get an array of objects, you just need to `map()` over the lines after you've `split()` on a `\n`. Do another split in `\t` and return the object:

```js
let str = "saddle (seat)\tasiento\nseat clamp\tabrazadera de asiento"
let trans = str.split('\n').map(line => {
    let [Eng, Spa] = line.split('\t')
    return {Eng, Spa}
})
console.log(trans)

// Get all Spa values:
console.log(trans.map(item => item.Spa))

// Get all Eng values:
console.log(trans.map(item => item.Eng))
```

**Edit Based on Comment**
You can's just print `trans.spa` because that could be many values. To get all the Spa values you need to use map to get them all with something like:

```
trans.map(item => item.Spa)
```

*(added to the excerpt above)*

Comment: how do I print out just the Spa values, something like this? 
console.log(trans.Spa) did not work for me

Comment: I've been trying to print out the console.log of the array into an html table, something goes wrong because node is server side. How could I print out the array of Spa into a html table? sorry to bug you again Mark